# Vb.net Error then use form4.show

Tags: vb.net

I have a little problem with my program. I just maked a little program. I have a problem with code "Form4.Show()".
I put this code on button and then press button I receive error:

> An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.IneerException for details. The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I don't know what code I put wrong ... this button have only form4.show.

PS: this error is from try catch.

This is button code.

```
Try 
    Form4.Show
Catch ex as Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

edit: all form4 code

```
Public Class Form4
    Dim txt As String = Textbox1.Text

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        txt = "450IP-Gift"
        Form5.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        txt = "450IP"
        Form5.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        txt = "1150IP-Gift"
        Form5.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        txt = "1150IP"
        Form5.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        txt = "3150IP-Gift"
        Form5.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        txt = "3150IP"
        Form5.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
        txt = "4800IP-Gift"
        Form5.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
        txt = "4800IP"
        Form5.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
        txt = "6300IP-Gift"
        Form5.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
        txt = "6300IP"
        Form5.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
        txt = "9600IP-Gift"
        Form5.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        txt = "9600IP"
        Form5.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: if there is code in Form New which references controls etc make sure it is AFTER 'Intitialize', if there is code in FormLoad, edit your post to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize `form4`

```
Try 
    Dim form4 = New Form4()
    form4.Show()
Catch ex as Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: I receive error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @terror, Is `Form4` initialized? Show us some more code. There is nothing in the try-catch block which will give error